# Twitter app does use my address book?

Tags: twitter, google-contacts

I would like to start using twitter on my smartphone but I do not want to share info with my contacts.

Does Twitter app for android suggest to my contacts to link to my accounts?

Answer (score 1):

In 2012 it was reported Twitter did upload the address book to their servers. Something changed after that. 
In case you're wondering if it has in the past you can visit https://twitter.com/settings/contacts_dashboard

If you are using Android 6.0 or higher you can disable the contact permissions as a extra precaution.

The Twitter app doesn't use your contacts unless you explicitly enable this in the settings of the app. Only way to identifies you with others that have is through your email (and mobile number)

Answer (score 0):

If you add your phone number and synchronise it, then only it use your contacts and keep you updating whom you may know. Who is already on Twitter. Whom you can invite using phone number. Otherwise it doesn't use address book.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the twitter website's help centre,

[Why is the Twitter app requesting permission to access features on my Android device?](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20171517?lang=en)

> When you install the Twitter for Android app on your device, you may
>   be prompted to grant permission for the app to access information or
>   use features from your device. Almost all apps need certain
>   permissions to run on Android, and we use these permissions to run
>   features in the Twitter for Android app. Keep in mind that Android
>   controls the way the permissions are named, and the way they are named
>   doesn’t necessarily reflect the way the Twitter app uses them.

And yes it is mentioned in the article and in you question, it reads you contacts for the purpose of friend suggestions,

> If you choose to import contacts from your device to Twitter, this
>   permission allows us to suggest friends to you in addition to
>   suggesting you to friends on Twitter.